# Combinatorial Maths for Groups

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 6 tables, of approximately 10-12 chairs;
There are 5 types of 70 members: 
18 Graduates
11 Directors
14 Managers
11 Senior Analysts
16 Senior Specialists

I would like an even distribution of each type on a table per round, but I would like to have a formula or a way of 'round robining' so that each member will meet one another at least once - without having the same membership in each round (keeping it as random as possible) - while keeping an even distribution of type.

What is the least amount of rounds with the least repetition of group members while keeping it as diverse as possible?
And what would be an example of the combinations in each round?

Comment: What does "approximately 10-12 chairs" mean? What does "the same membership each round" or "as random as possible" mean? What is "as diverse as possible"? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: We had a similar question a few months ago with only two groups of people and it didn't get a complete answer. I think you're best off just trying some kind of directed random search for a "good enough" solution.